# Azure SignalROutput handle failed execution

Tags: c#, azure, azure-functions, azure-signalr

I am using `BlobTriggerFunction` with output binding as `SignalROutput`, Now If `Azure SignalR` is not configured, it throws error and **runs functions again and again**.

How can I make sure to execute output binding only once either failed or success.
Meaning If there is AzureSignalR URL is working then it will trigger otherwise simply ignore that.

Here is sample code

Issue : If I don't have `Azure SignalR` output binding failed and it `retries` whole function again and in my `DB FileBlob` are created multiple times.

I have tried setting retry in `host.json` but it didn't help.

```
    "retry": {
        "maximumInterval" : 1
    }
```

```
[Function("BlobTriggerFunction")]
[SignalROutput(HubName = "hub", ConnectionStringSetting = "AzureSignalRConnectionString")]
public static async Task<SignalRViewModel> Run([BlobTrigger("mycontainer/{name}", Connection = BlobConnectionStr")] string myBlob, string name, Uri Uri,
    FunctionContext context)
{
    var logger = context.GetLogger("BlobTriggerFunction");
    logger.LogInformation($"C# Blob trigger function Processed blob\n Name: {name}");
    
    var optionsBuilder = new DbContextOptionsBuilder<MyContext>();
    var connectionString = Environment.GetEnvironmentVariable("ConnectionStrings");
    optionsBuilder.UseSqlServer(connectionString);
    
    var fileBlob = new FileBlob
    {
        Name = name,
        IsDeleted = false
    };
    _ctx.FileBlobs.Add(fileBlob);
    await _ctx.SaveChangesAsync();
    
    return SignalRViewModel signalRVM = new SignalRViewModel()
    {
        Target = "hub",
        UserId = data.userId,
        Arguments = new[] { "default" }
    };
}
```

**Error**
 `2022-05-18T13:50:09.899Z] Executed 'Functions.BlobTriggerFunction' (Failed, Id=f3fb531d-41d1-48eb-a266-75afb92605a9, Duration=214ms) [2022-05-18T13:50:09.902Z] System.Private.CoreLib: Exception while executing function: Functions.BlobTriggerFunction.`
`Microsoft.Azure.SignalR.Management: Unable to access SignalR service. No such host is known. Please make sure the endpoint or DNS setting is correct. Request Uri: https://my-test.service.signalr.net/api/v1/hubs/hub/users/0. System.Net.Http: No such host is known. System.Private.CoreLib: No such host is known.`

Comment: [Troubleshooting guide for Azure SignalR Service common issues](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-signalr/signalr-howto-troubleshoot-guide) and [Use private endpoints for Azure SignalR Service](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-signalr/howto-private-endpoints)

Comment: @DeepDave-MT My issue is with Functions, If Azure SignalR is up then it's working fine but I need a solution for what if I disable SignalR